# Showing Div Not Working On Select Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show the FILE DIV if the user selects the doctor value in the select statement. I know the if statement works because I also print the value in the console which works perfectly fine. I toggle my divs in the same exact manner in my other webpages so I'm not understanding what's going on with this one in particular.

```js
function viewFile(){
        var file = document.getElementById("doclicense");
        var type = document.getElementById('accountType').value;
        if(type === 'doctor') {
            file.style.display = "block";
            console.log(type);
        } 
    }
```

```css
.hidden{
display : none;
}
```

```html
<div> 
<select id="accountType" name="type" class="form-control" onchange="viewFile()"> 
<option required>Account Type</option>
                        <option value="doctor" name="doctor" id="doctor">Doctor</option>
                        <option value="regular" name="regular" id="reg">Regular Account</option>
                    </select>
</div>

                <div class="hidden file" id="doclicense">
                    <input type="file" name="license"  />
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </div>
```

****************************************EDIT-WORKAROUND**********************

Since my code refused to work, I added a line of code with 'head' being the title and not a real value. Thanks to everyone who contributed. I took out the hidden class altogether but when I add it, it still doesn't work correctly.

```
 function viewDocFile() {
        var file = document.getElementById("doclicense");
        var type = document.getElementById('accountType').value;
        if (type === 'regular' || type === 'head') {
            file.style.display = "none"; 
            console.log(type);
        } else { 
            file.style.display = "block";
            console.log(type);
            }
        }
```

***************************FINAL-EDIT************************
Kept the original code, but added the CSS inline.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6" id="doclicense" style="display:none;">
```

Works perfectly now.

Comment: What is the question. Do you want explanation of the code?...

Comment: It's not working. I want it to show the div if the selected value is doctor. The if statement works because it's being printed in the console, which is what I wanted to happen as well as showing the div.

Comment: The `<div class="hidden file" id="doclicense">` is already shown. Its not hidden.

Comment: @MaheerAli - I'd suggest there's CSS involved

Comment: it is hidden. I can't get it to show at all. Added hidden class css

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: display : none; not display = none;

Comment: `.hidden{
display = none;
}` WONT hide the div, so not sure why your div is hidden

Comment: Clearly the problem is caused by some other code or css you are not sharing - see my answer, a runnable snippet, that clearly works

Comment: I've shown three possible reasons your code doesn't work in my answer below

Comment: Your snippet works just fine - so it must be a typo

Comment: This is a very bad code .. bad variable names (file, type) you use a submit for a non-existent form, you use a class that you do not delete when its property is no longer valid, you declare global variables in a function. ...  use name attribute for option elements...

Comment: I have yet to clean it up but thanks for the constructive criticism. Changed var names. I used the name attribute because I'm also using php so I'll need it for inserting the specific type to the database.

Comment: Have you always had an else with a console.log? because you know it may have been going through there all the time if you have a, say, zero width white space character in the doctor string

Comment: The option element can not have a name attribute, it is in the standard HTML. https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/global-attributes.html#global-attributes

Comment: how can `type === 'head'`? see, as I suspected all along, the code you posted is only vaguely similar to the actual code you're having an issue with ... seeing as the div is successfully shown by *your original code* I can't see this as anything but a typo error and flagged it as can't reproduce or typo

Comment: read the sentence above it. I just added it so it could work. I posted exactly what I had in my code. I wouldn't post anything different if I came on here asking for help.

Comment: does your snippet in your question show the doctor div if you select doctor? so, how is that "not working"

Comment: You can not have `class="hidden"` and `style.display = "block";` at the same time, that's the reason for your bugg. Look at the code that I propose following you, it is simpler and clearer to understand than yours, because it must also be easy to read for others

Comment: it comes up in the console, but the form did not pop up @jaro

Comment: form `popup`? well, there's no "popup" forms to be seen in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this code should be written (even if there are still horrors)

```js
// declare them here and not in a function where they will be redone each time the function is called

const
  file_IHM  = document.querySelector('#doclicense')
  ,
  type_IHM  = document.querySelector('#accountType')  // and not with .value ...!
;


type_IHM.onchange = function()
{
  file_IHM.style.display = (this.value==='doctor')?"block":"none"; 

  console.log('type_IHM.value',  this.value );

}
```

```css
#doclicense { display : none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="accountType" name="type" class="form-control" >  <!--  let the js in the js part -->
    <option required>Account Type</option>
    <option value="doctor"  id="doctor"  >Doctor</option>
    <option value="regular" id="regular" >Regular Account</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="file-class" id="doclicense">  <!--  do not use class="hidden... -->
  <input type="file" name="license" />
  <input type="submit" />   <!-- there is no form anywhere...   why don't you use <button> ?? -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If that what your code really looks like, did you add your js in a `<script></script>` tag?
Or do you want to toggle the hide and show of the div?
if so this answer may help

```
<select id="accountType" name="type" class="form-control" onchange="viewFile()"><option required>Account Type</option>
                        <option value="doctor" name="doctor" id="doctor">Doctor</option>
                        <option value="regular" name="regular" id="reg">Regular Account</option>
     </select>
                </div>

                <div class="hidden file" id="doclicense">
                    <input type="file" name="license"  />
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </div>
<script>
function viewFile(){
        var file = document.getElementById("doclicense");
        var type = document.getElementById('accountType').value;
        if(type === 'doctor') {
            file.style.display = "block";
            console.log(type);
        }else{
             file.style.display = "none";
            console.log(type);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: does your script is within the same file as the other elements?

Comment: @Francisaskquestion -since the console.log works, I'd say that's a moot point